# cxf POST fails on ubuntu

Tags: post, ubuntu, cxf

We have apache CXF application that works on windows but doesn't work on Ubuntu. GET requests works, but POST request doesn't receive message body. 
class Upload that receives messages:

```
@Path("/api/user/{userId}")
public class Upload {
  @POST
  @Path("upload")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  public FileRecord upload(@PathParam("userId") String userId, 
                           @QueryParam("key") String accessKey,
                           @Multipart(value="FileRecord", type=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) FileRecord fileRecord,
                           @Multipart(value="BodyRecord", type=MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) InputStream body) {
```

fileRecord is null on ubuntu, but okay on windows.

Message that we send:
(header)

```
POST http://192.168.1.71:9000/api/user/tdq/upload HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: application/json
MIME-Version: 1.0
content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary="123"
Content-Length: 443
Host: 192.168.1.71:9000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

(body)

```
--123
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileRecord"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-ID: FileRecord

{"FileRecord":{"name":"UploadTest"}}
--123
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BodyRecord"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-ID: BodyRecord

This is a body
--123
```

Comment: We decided not to use @Multipart(value="FileRecord", type=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) FileRecord fileRecord as parameter, but have String parameter instead and parse json string for this class.